# Vite.js + TS + Module Federation - not working with basic configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, webpack-module-federation

I'm using the latest Vite with React 18 and trying to integrate a module federation architecture.
After running application on the server side I got this error:

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at main.tsx:7.
>
> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

My configuration is just a simple, empty create vite project.
The only addon is *@originjs/vite-plugin-federation* of course.

**vite.config.ts**

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/my-app',
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'my_app',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './Initializer': './src/Initializer',
      },
      shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    }),
  ],
})
```

**main.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import Initializer from "./Initializer.tsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Initializer/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

**Initializer.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App.tsx";

function Initializer(): React.ReactElement {

  return (
    <App/>
  )
}

export default Initializer;
```

App.tsx - no change comparing to ne created project.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.18",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite --port=3000 --strictPort",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview --port=3000 --strictPort",
    "serve": "vite preview --port=3000 --strictPort",
    "sonar-scanner": "sonar-scanner",
    "half-prod": "npm run build",
    "full-prod": "npm i && npm run half-prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation": "^1.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@swc/cli": "^0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.86",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```